# Why Variable value is not changed after calling the function

Tags: php

If a variable is defined outside a function and again it defined inside the function then why the value of variable is not changed after calling the function.

```
$a = 12;

Function abc()
{
    $a=15; 
    echo $a;
}

abc(); 
echo $a;
```

OUTPUT:

```
1512
```

Why not:

```
1515
```

Comment: Declare like this `global $a`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `global` keyword ( or sometimes `$GLOBALS['a']` )

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
$a=12;

function abc(){
    global $a;
    $a=15; 
    echo $a;
}

abc(); 
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because variable scope is limit to function body, you can make the variable global if you want to use the above variable like:

```
function abc() {
   global $a;
}
```